# Problems with native Win32api RichEdit control and its IRichEditOle interface

Tags: c#, com, com-interop, ole

As part of writing custom command (COM-Visible dll with class that implements Interwoven command interface) for one of Interwoven Worksite dialog boxes, I need to extract information from RichEdit textbox.

The only connection to the existing dialog box is its HWND handle; seemingly trivial task , but I got stuck:

- Using standard win32 api functions (like GetDlgItemText) returns empty string.

After using Spy++ I noticed that the dialog box gets `IRichEditOle` interface and seems to encapsulate the string into OLE object.

Here is what I tried to do:

```
IRichEditOle richEditOleObj = null; 
IntPtr ppv = IntPtr.Zero; 
Guid guid = new Guid("00020D00-0000-0000-c000-000000000046"); 
Marshal.QueryInterface(pRichEdit, ref guid, out ppv); 
richEditOleObj = (IRichEditOle)Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(ppv,typeof(IRichEditOle));
```

Judging by `GetObjectCount()` method of the interface there is exactly one object in the textbox - most likely the string I need to extract. I used `GetObject()` method and got `IOleObject` interface via `QueryInterface`:

```
if (richEditOleObj.GetObject(0, reObject, GetObjectOptions.REO_GETOBJ_ALL_INTERFACES) == 0) //S_OK
{ 
    IntPtr oleObjPpv = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    { 
        IOleObject oleObject = null; 
        Guid objGuid = new Guid("00000112-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"); 
        Marshal.QueryInterface(reObject.poleobj, ref objGuid, out oleObjPpv);
        oleObject = (IOleObject)Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(oleObjPpv, typeof(IOleObject));
```

To negate other possibilites I tried to QueryInteface for `IRichEditOle` to `ITextDocument` but this also returned empty string.

I tried to send `EM_STREAMOUT` message and read buffer returned from callback - returned empty buffer.

On this point I got stuck. Googling didn't help much - couldn't find anything that was relevant to my issue - it seems that vast majority of examples on the net about `IRichEditOle` and RichEdit revolve around inserting bitmap into RichEdit control.

The main problem - I couldn't find a way to extract information I needed from `IOleObject` interface and didn't find any examples relevant to extracting data from the object.

Now since I know only basic stuff about COM and OLE , I guess I am missing something important here.

I would appreciate any thoughts suggestions or remarks.

Comment: Why are you not using the RichEditBox class?  Does this control belong to another process?

Comment: Yes. Interwoven Worksite is client-server application , and I am developing extension for one of client's dialog boxes; The only connection I have to Worksite's client is HWND handle I get trough its COM api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the missing bit of the puzzle. Perhaps what I did will help others with similar problem.

After calling `IRichEditOle::GetObject` I received `REOBJECT` structure. By using **clsid** field of the structure I found via registry the dll where needed interface was defined.

Using explicit cast (This is C#; so it is equivalent to using QueryInterface) from `IOleObject` to the required interface I achieved what I needed - access to the data stored in that `IOleObject`.